# actions not working inside componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, video.js, rangeslider

I am using react-redux in my application. I have a player and i used rangesliderplugin for videojs. I have an actioncreater which should get triggered when I slide the slider in video timeline. There is a plugin given on https://github.com/danielcebrian/rangeslider-videojs for that. I want to pass a value to my action from this event function. Here is my code

newMarkerTime is my action

```
class PlayerLogic extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            player: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var self = this;
        var options ={hidden:false};
        var player = videojs(this.refs.video, this.props.options).ready(function () {
            self.player = this;
            self.player.on('play', self.handlePlay);
        });
        player.rangeslider(options);
        player.on("sliderchange",function() {
            values = player.getValueSlider();
            this.props.newMarkerTime(values);
        });
```

This give in an error like this when i slide the slider.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a fat arrow here, or use `self` which you declared above

```
player.on("sliderchange",function() {
  values = player.getValueSlider();
  // this refers to player
  this.props.newMarkerTime(values);
  // self refers to your component
  self.props.newMarkerTime(values);
});

// use a fat arrow instead
player.on("sliderchange", () => {
  values = player.getValueSlider();
  // this refers to your react component
  this.props.newMarkerTime(values);
});
```

Comment: Worked. Can you please explain what is the logic behind using arrow function here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions